# I can't make this query work with SUM function

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00904, ora-00979

This query gives an error:

```
select ep, 
  case
    when ob is null and b2b_ob is null then 'a'
    when ob is not null or b2b_ob is not null then 'b'
    else null
  end as type,
  sum(b2b_d + b2b_t - b2b_i) as sales
from table
where ...
group by ep, type
```

Error: ORA-00904: "TYPE": invalid identifier

When I run it with `group by ep`, the error message becomes:

ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

The whole query works OK if I remove the lines `sum(b2b_d+b2b_t-b2b_i) as sales` and `group by ...`, so the problem should be related to SUM and GROUP BY functions. How can I make this work? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately SQL doesn't allow you to use the column aliases in the GROUP BY clause, so you either have to repeat the entire CASE there like this:

```
select ep, 
  case
    when ob is null and b2b_ob is null then 'a'
    when ob is not null or b2b_ob is not null then 'b'
    else null
  end as type,
  sum(b2b_d + b2b_t - b2b_i) as sales
from table
where ...
group by ep,
  case
    when ob is null and b2b_ob is null then 'a'
    when ob is not null or b2b_ob is not null then 'b'
    else null
  end
```

or use an in-line view like this:

```
select ep, 
  type,
  sum(b2b_d + b2b_t - b2b_i) as sales
from
( select ep, 
    case
      when ob is null and b2b_ob is null then 'a'
      when ob is not null or b2b_ob is not null then 'b'
      else null
    end as type,
    b2b_d,
    b2b_t,
    b2b_i
  from table
  where ...
)
group by ep, type
```